# How can I get the output of Ansible ad-hoc command in JSON, CSV or other format?

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

What is the way to get the output of Ansible ad-hoc command in JSON, CSV or other format?

Answer (score 7):

You could also do it through the environment variables if you do not want to modify the `.cfg` file, for example:

```bash
ANSIBLE_LOAD_CALLBACK_PLUGINS=true \
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json \
ansible all \
  -a "df -h /tmp"
```

More info on Ansible environment variables here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#environment-variables.

Answer (score 4):

In `ansible.cfg` add:

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = json
```

See [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback/json.html)

Instead of this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "test"
}
```

You will have:

```
{
    "plays": [
        {
            "play": {
                "id": "720000f8-9450-586c-9a68-000000000005", 
                "name": "Json Test"
            }, 
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "hosts": {
                        "localhost": {
                            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                            "_ansible_verbose_always": true, 
                            "changed": false, 
                            "msg": "test"
                        }
                    }, 
                    "task": {
                        "id": "720000f8-9450-586c-9a68-000000000007", 
                        "name": "Debug"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "stats": {
        "localhost": {
            "changed": 0, 
            "failures": 0, 
            "ok": 1, 
            "skipped": 0, 
            "unreachable": 0
        }
    }
}
```

For the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Json Test
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars: 
    test: test


  tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ test  }}"
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Clintm (below), you will also need to add the `bin_ansible_callbacks = True` directive to `~/.ansible.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use at least Ansible 2.5

and then set this in your ansible config:

```
stdout_callback = json
bin_ansible_callbacks = True
```

A quick note (complaint?) about ansible config... config files are not additive. 
If you have multiple config files (e.g. /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg and ~/.ansible.cfg) it will only take values from ~/.ansible.

Here's the config file order:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file

Here's the bug:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17914

Also here's the full callback plugin list:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list

Comment: This worked for me. I was missing the `bin_ansible_callbacks = True` directive in `~/.ansible.cfg`. Having added that, I get JSON output from `ansible(1)` ad-hoc commands. Thank you.